# Nullable type conversion in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

can we assign null value to struct type of variable?

```
struct MyStruct
{
}

MyStruct var = null;
```

is this is possible in C# .net?

if not ? then  how C# is allowing Nullable < T > struct  type of variable can be assigned as null?

Comment: and even after asking 7 questions he has not learnt how to use formatting.

Comment: hello Nullable<T> is struct type how complier accepts null for this type ? why not it accept same struct type of variable ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the subject of:

> ... how C# is allowing Nullable < T > struct type of variable can be assigned as null?

The answer is actually quite simple: The C# compiler knows about `Nullable<T>` and handles it as a special case to maintain the illusion.

For example, this:

```
int? a;
if (a != null) ...
```

Actually compiles into this:

```
if (a.HasValue) ...
```

Virtually all of this magic is handled by the compiler -- .NET mostly views `Nullable<T>` as just another ValueType. I remember reading (most likely from [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/)), that late in the development process they discovered one edge issue that just could not be handled by compiler tricks alone. The runtime folks agreed to make one change that treated `Nullable<T>` as a special case. Unfortunately, I don't remember what the special case was and I can't find the reference anymore.

Please review this article for details (especially the second comment which is by Lippert):
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible but you have to declare your variable as 'nullable':

```
MyStruct? foo = null;
```

or

```
Nullable<MyStruct> foo = null;
```

Comment: hello Nullable<T> is struct type how complier accepts null for this type ?

why not it accept same struct type of variable ??

Comment: @dinesh. Indeed, the compiler cannot accept null for a non-nullable type. Nullable<T> is a type by its own. It decorates the inner non-nullable type with some code logic which emulates the null behavior; by providing some properties (HasValue, Value) and some implicit cast operators.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `struct`s are value types, whereas `class`es are reference types.

`struct`s can't be made `null`, so you must use the `Nullable<T>` class to wrap it into something that can be nullified.

This is done by either directly using the `Nullable<T>` class in the declaration:

```
Nullable<MyStruct> foo;
```

Or by using the syntactic sugar for `Nullable<T>`:

```
MyStruct? foo;
```

Comment: hello Nullable<T> is struct type how complier accepts null for this type ? why not it accept same struct type of variable ??

Answer (score 0):

Structs cannot be null, [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx) are used to create instances of nullable structs.